# MongoDB log file size

Tags: mongodb

I'm developing a system around mongodb (version 2.0.1) environment for finance company.
I have noticed that mongodb log file keep growing - in couple of days it became 65 GB consuming all hard disk space.

How can i limit mongodb log file? Is there a way to tell mongo not to log any operation?
I already tell mongo to use minimal log but it's not enough.
Also, rotateFile command is not working in windows.
The file is exclusive open by mongo so i can't delete or truncate.

Regards

Comment: Welcome to SO, for server related questions look at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: MongoDB log rotate solve it. See the detail discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004626/mongodb-log-file-growth.

Comment: `db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 } )` ;)

Answer (score 0):

The mongodb rotateFile issue in windows is fixed now from version 2.0.3/2.1.0. check the jira ticket for more info [support logRotate under windows](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2612).

You can upgrade your mongo server to the latest. I believe this is the only way.

Comment: As said in the jira ticket comment by Tad marshal ' A backport to 2.0.x might be worthwhile – the code changes are fairly small, just one function in one file.' If you dont want the development release. you can download the stable 2.0.2 version src from github and compile your own. the commit hash for the issue is b1684bb3dfdcd4101cc605022258a632f4b38d32. refer the ticket for more clarity

Comment: and how to activate this so called logRotate? How to make that automatic every time we start a server? Is this activated by Default?