# Why do we need to rotate the MongoDB log?

Tags: mongodb

We got a performance issue on our Python Web Application and it was resolved when i did the log rotation on MongoDb,

**db.adminCommand( { logRotate : 1 } )**

it seems that the cause of the issue is related with the mongodb.

Why do we need to log rotate mongodb? 
Is there anything we can check/monitor when do we need to log rotate?
What are the things we need to check if encounters mongodb related issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purpose is to prevent the log file from getting to big. It the same principle with almost any log files. If the log files get to big you might: 
* start running out of disk space 
* write times get slower (depends)
* if something parses that log it will have a harder time doing it, in extreme cases (I've seen solutions that loaded the whole log file to memory for processing...) it might cause those parsers to crash
* it's harder to navigate and archive

Mongodb has a [built-in to manage log rotation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/) -- controlled by the command you mentioned. It can probably be also managed by logrotate (mother of log rotation solutions).

Also check out this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004626/mongodb-log-file-growth).

Comment: Do you know the capacity of the mongodb size? How can we check if the mongodb is running out of disk space?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: Well, I'd rather check the available space on the server running mongodb. Usually you want to have some sort of alerting system in place that will notify you when you exceed a given capacity threshold e.g. disk is 80% full. If you want to do it manually then a simple `df -h` will do.

Comment: Hi Sir, Thanks! It helps a lot. :) Hope i can help you someday.